# Promise with two for loops nested Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to create an asynchronous method with promise but I can't understand why it doesn't worked with my program below :

```
app.get('/historique', function (req, res) {

  const pathFolders = `.\\..\\website\\src\\assets\\covering\\`;

  const promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    fs.readdirSync(pathFolders).forEach(folder => {

      recursive(`${pathFolders}\\${folder}\\`, function (err, files) {

        var datapath = [];

        files.forEach(file => {

          console.log("1");

        });

        console.log("2");
      });

      console.log("3");
      resolve("3");
    });

  });

  promise2.then(function (value) {
    console.log("end")
    res.status(200).send("end")
  });

})
```

Normally, I would like the program to show in the order on the console.log 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 ... then 3 and finally "end".
But the console.log show me first 3 then "end" then 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...

Can you help me please. I think this is because of the for loop but I can't solve this problem.

Comment: What is the `recursive` function? It seems that the function is asyncronous, then it makes sense the code jumps over and go to the console.log("3") before executing it.

Comment: Yes totally, but normally the promise can enable asynchronous function. So I don't undertand why it is not working

Comment: const recursive = require("recursive-readdir");

Comment: Try to add return to the promise:    return resolve("3")

Comment: Notice that is statement is false: "normally the promise can enable asynchronous function." In practice, Promises are objects that run callbacks after its `resolve` (or `reject`) function is called. The code inside its main function does not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As E. Zacarias already explained in his comment, the `recursive-readdir` implementation is implemented asynchronously. But it supports being used with a `Promise` by leaving out the callback argument.

Then you can return a `Promise` from the iterator function and wait for it with `Promise.all`.

This will make your code much more straightforward:

```
app.get('/historique', function (req, res) {

  const pathFolders = `.\\..\\website\\src\\assets\\covering\\`;

  const promise2 = Promise.all(
    // readdirSync returns an Array of folder name strings
    // Call Array.map to transform it into an array of Promise
    fs.readdirSync(pathFolders).map(folder => {
      // return a Promise for the folder from the map function
      return recursive(`${pathFolders}\\${folder}\\`).then(files => {
        var datapath = [];
        files.forEach(file => {
          console.log("1");
        });
        console.log("2");
      });
    });
  );

  promise2.then( value => {
    console.log("end")
    res.status(200).send("end")
  });

})
```

The important aspects here are to understand the workings of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Thank's a lot it works. But I don't really understand what is the real difference between your code and my code.

Comment: I think that the return and the map on the array are very useful but I don't understand why it is so useful.

Comment: I'll amend the answer with a more verbose explanation!